# Boolean conditions java

Tags: java, android, class, variables

I have class, that has some vars. One of them is boolean variable, that controls moves through array(if it's true, start from beginning, if false, start from remembered position)

Here is part of bool variable.

```
boolean fromStart;
fromStart = vars.isFromStart();
public void setFromStart(boolean fromStart) {
    this.fromStart = fromStart;
}   


public boolean isFromStart() {
    return fromStart;
}
```

and this is how i used this bool var

```
 if (vars.isFromStart){
            i = 0;
            vars.setFromStart(false);
        }
        else {
            loadPos(i);
            i = getIntent().getIntExtra(pos, i);
        }
```

And this is code, where i try to change values:

```
public void fromLastClick(View view) {
    var.setFromStart(false);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

public void startClick(View view) {
    var.setFromStart(false);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ChangeFacts.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

but it's always started from beginning(looks like bool variable is always true). What i doing wrong?

Comment: The if statement checks for the Variable fromStart. But it seems to be set before (using vars.isFromStart() ) try using if (vars.isFromStart())

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the full code it seems that you are assigning the value false to a boolean called fromStart inside a object called "vars", but you are checking a boolean variable with the same name in your main class instead of the one in "vars" object

Try modifying your if condition:

```
if (vars.isFromStart())
```

Comment: i've changed my description a bit. could you look pls?

Comment: Can you show the whole var class? It's sometimes called vars, sometimes var.  Also, you are initializing the var object in a class and using them in another class? If so are you sharing your var object?